# MySQL query that joins 3 tables gives wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I use a database (structure attached below) with users that request an object (request table) or reply to a request (action table).

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYZ1p.jpg)

(Note: `request.user_request_id` is the ID of the requester)

I want to find a query that gives me the users that either did a request or replied to a request during a month along with the number of requests, the number of replies and the total ( requests + replies).

I´ve got a working query for the number of requests for March 2018:

```
SELECT user.email, COUNT(request.user_request_id) AS requests 
FROM request LEFT JOIN user ON request.user_request_id = user.id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(request.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') 
= '2018-03' 
GROUP BY user_request_id 
ORDER BY number desc;
```

And one for the number of replies:

```
SELECT user.email, COUNT(action.lender_id) AS replies 
FROM action LEFT JOIN user ON action.lender_id = user.id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(action.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') = 
'2018-03' 
GROUP BY lender_id 
ORDER BY number desc;
```

But if I try to use a single query across the 3 tables it goes wrong. (For example for a user that made 3 requests and 4 replies it gives me 9 requests and 9 replies.) 
Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT user.email, 
COUNT(request.user_request_id) AS requests, 
COUNT(action.lender_id) AS replies, 
COUNT(request.user_request_id) + COUNT(action.lender_id) AS total 
FROM request LEFT JOIN user ON user.id=request.user_request_id LEFT JOIN 
action ON request.object_id=action.object_id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(request.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') 
= '2018-03' 
OR DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(action.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') = 
'2018-03' 
GROUP BY user.email 
ORDER BY total desc;
```

Anyone sees what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: please post sample data and expected results - ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: You should store your dates as `DATETIME` objects. They'll be a lot more space efficient , will help you handle timezones etc, and best of all you can index them and use `WHERE datefield BETWEEN ` the start and end date.  Your way, you have to transform every date and compare, which precludes an index on what would otherwise greatly reduce the table scanning.  Never put a date in a string or int.  You can also auto-create and auto-fill datefields when created or updated: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't make the same LEFT JOIN

In the second request you make the join between action and user using `"action.lender_id = user.id"` but in the third query you make the join between request and action using `"request.object_id=action.object_id"` so basically you ll not get the same results

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `JOIN` condition.  You join `request` and `action` on `object_id`, but not on `request_id`.  Your current query will `JOIN` each row of request to all rows of action what satisfy condition on `object_id`.

```
SELECT user.email, 
    COUNT(request.user_request_id) AS requests, 
    COUNT(action.lender_id) AS replies, 
    COUNT(request.user_request_id) + COUNT(action.lender_id) AS total 
FROM request 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = request.user_request_id 
LEFT JOIN action ON request.object_id = action.object_id  AND request.user_request_id = action.request_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(request.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') = '2018-03' 
    OR DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(action.created_at, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m') = '2018-03' 
GROUP BY user.email 
ORDER BY total desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

For querying based on dates, and in your scenario, looking for anything for March, 2018 (via 2018-03 string value),  You will not get any optimization on a date field when you have to convert every date to a string and THEN see if it fits.

Instead, you know the month/year, so set your where clause to the first and LESS than the day after the end.  Ex: You want March, 2018.  So >= '2018-03-01' no problem.  For the end, if your dates have time possibilities and you want to include up to March 31 at 11:59:59pm, you would do LESS than '2018-04-01'.  So now you get the whole month in question and CAN utilize an index based on your created_at date/time field.

Next part is you JOIN to the actions.  Actions you had as a left-join meaning all requests regardless of an action being found.  HOWEVER, you then added your ACTION Date as part of the where clause thus changing it to an INNER JOIN (even though part of an OR between criteria).  This will result in any requests within the time period that DID NOT have an action as EXCLUDED from the result set.  You probably need to shift that to the JOIN clause.  Of which, is it really needed?  The action would never be before the request, but what about a request on March 29 that has actions done on March 30, Apr 1, Apr 2.  Do you want the resulting count of 1 (Just Mar 29), or 3 (inclusive of Apr 1 and Apr 2).

Other simple adjustment.  All requests MUST have a user ID, but you have that as a left-join.  Its a 1:1 ratio so that probably SHOULD be set as a normal INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
      u.email, 
      COUNT(r.user_request_id) AS requests, 
      COUNT(a.lender_id) AS replies, 
      COUNT(r.user_request_id) + COUNT(a.lender_id) AS total 
   FROM 
      request r
         INNER JOIN user u
            ON r.user_request_id = u.id
         LEFT JOIN action a
            ON r.object_id = a.object_id 
            -- if you explicitly want to RESTRICT Actions within same date range
            AND a.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
            AND a.created_at < '2018-04-01'
   WHERE 
          r.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
      AND r.created_at < '2018-04-01'
   GROUP BY 
      u.email 
   ORDER BY 
      total desc;
```

Now, you mention incorrect answers as you tried the above similar query trying to do in a single shot.  This is probably due to a Cartesian result.  For every one record in a request that has a reply, you are now getting that count applied multiple times.  You probably need to keep each individual respective count as it's own query so for a given user its only counted properly ONCE per respective user/lender

```
SELECT 
      u.email,
      coalesce( R1.RequestCnt, 0 ) Requests,
      coalesce( A1.ActionCnt, 0 ) Replies,
      coalesce( R1.RequestCnt, 0 ) 
         + coalesce( A1.ActionCnt, 0 ) AS total 
   FROM 
      user u
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( select 
                 r.user_request_id as userID, 
                 count(*) requestCnt
              from 
                 request r
              WHERE 
                     r.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
                 AND r.created_at < '2018-04-01'
              group by 
                 r.user_request_id ) R1
            ON u.id = R1.userID

         LEFT JOIN
         ( select 
                 a.lender_id as userID, 
                 count(*) actionCnt
              from 
                 action a
              WHERE 
                     a.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
                 AND a.created_at < '2018-04-01'
              group by 
                 a.lender_id ) A1
            ON u.id = A1.userID
   where 
      coalesce( R1.RequestCnt, 0 ) 
         + coalesce( A1.ActionCnt, 0 ) > 0
   ORDER BY 
      coalesce( R1.RequestCnt, 0 ) 
         + coalesce( A1.ActionCnt, 0 ) desc;
```

Now, if you have a large set of uses (such as millions), we can shorten the query one step further by pre-getting a list of distinct users within the date period in question...

```
   from
      ( select distinct
              r.user_request_id as userID
           from 
              request r
           WHERE 
                  r.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
              AND r.created_at < '2018-04-01'
        UNION
        select a.lender_id as userID
           from 
              action a
           WHERE 
                  a.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
              AND a.created_at < '2018-04-01' ) as UniqUsers
          JOIN user u
             on UniqUsers.UserID = u.id
             -- rest of the other pre-queries above...
```